# Modifying / Adding to C# Partial Classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, partial-classes, self-modifying

I have got a partial class in my C# project i.e. auto-generated code from Entity Framework. Now I want to modify or add some more functionalities, properties or methods to that class. I have the auto-generated class code under `EntityFrameworkModel.tt\Author.cs` tab in the project while the other related classes are in another folder i.e. `GraphData` in the same project.

I also know that the name of partial classes should be same while file name may be different or same as well. I did same but when I defined the object for `Author.cs` as:

```
protected override EvoObject ConvertCPV(Author _author)  
{
    if (_author.???)  
    {
        //...  
    }
}
```

I can't access the methods defined in `GraphData\Author.cs` (The question marks in example code) whereas the properties defined in `EntityFrameworkModel.tt\Author.cs` are only accessible.

Here I attached the `Solution Explorer` image as:

[image]

How can I access the properties and methods from both classes?

Comment: Including the namespaces where were declared both classes

Comment: @octavioccl I have added still unable to access

Comment: @octavioccl good point, definitely check that to make sure the namespaces match in both files, otherwise it is really two different partial classes you are defining. I would also check to make sure your `GraphData\Author.cs` file is included with the `Build Action` of `Compile`, to make sure it is actually getting compiled into your assembly.

Comment: You can simply add another partial class with the same namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar set up in a project also.

To keep things tidy I also have folders where I place certain partial classes, you just need to ensure the namespace is the same as the auto generated class.

When you add a new class to a folder the namespace will automatically contain the name of the folder - you can just remove the folder name from the namespace - you should just have the Project name in this scenario.

**If the namespaces are different then the partial classes are not part of the same class.** This is why you can't access the new functions/Properties.

Also, even though your file name and class names can be different, it is better to keep them the same - it will be easier to find a class if the file has the same name.

Comment: Namespaces are same but when I remove folder name as: `Namespace.FolderName` when I remove folder name, I got an error that `FolderName` doesn't exist while compiling and also I then be able to access all properties from both

Comment: Why can't I add other partial class in separate folder ?

Comment: Is the error because you are using the `Namespace.FolderName` in another part of your code somewhere? Now that you have removed the `FolderName` from the Partial Class, you do not need to use `Namespace.FolderName` in the other parts of your code.

Comment: @Rick--if I don't use `Namespace.FolderName` in other parts of my code, then still the files and codes changes are saved in the same file/folder ?

Comment: Yes - the actual files and code are still in the folder.

Comment: Happy to help - this might help you understand a bit more about namespaces  [MSDN Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz9ayh33(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

- Make your own class outside of EntityFrameworkModel.tt - name it Author.cs, make the class partial.

The whole idea of partial is to allow code generators not to care about your code. Of you modify a generated class, the next regeneration kills the changes.

> I did same but when I defined the object for Author.cs as:

Ah, no, you did not because then you claim your definition is:

> protected override EvoObject ConvertCPV(Author _author)

Which is NOT defining the object.

> I can't access the methods defined in GraphData\Author.cs

Because namespace? Check the namespaces - bad to have them in a subfolder when they belong in a the same namespace as EntityFrameworkModel.tt

> whereas the properties defined in EntityFrameworkModel.tt\Author.cs are only 
>   accessible.

Partial classes do not allow changes in another partial - not for the moment, a substition syntax is considered.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

It says `"The partial keyword indicates that other parts of the class, struct, or interface can be defined in the namespace."` It does not explicitly state this, but that implies that the partial definitions of the class must be declared in the *same* namespace. It doesn't matter which files in the project contain the classes, or what folders they are in.

```
using System;

namespace DemoConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SameNamespace.PartialClass.MethodOne();
            SameNamespace.PartialClass.MethodTwo();
            DifferentNamespace.PartialClass.MethodThree();
        }
    }
}

namespace SameNamespace
{
    public partial class PartialClass
    {
        public static void MethodOne()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method One.");
        }
    }

    public partial class PartialClass
    {
        public static void MethodTwo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method Two.");
        }
    }
}

namespace DifferentNamespace
{
    public partial class PartialClass
    {
        public static void MethodThree()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method Three.");
        }
    }
}
```